# ¿Cómo saber cuantos registros se repiten en Mysql?

Tags: mysql

Necesito contar los registros que se repiten en un campo de mi base de datos. hasta el momento he logrado saber cuales son los que se repiten. Este es mi código:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.id_producto, COUNT(*) AS num
FROM tabla_precio AS a 
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) 
             FROM tabla_precio AS b 
             WHERE a.id_producto = b.id_producto) > 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes mejorar el query utilizando las cláusulas `GROUP BY` y `HAVING`:

```sql
SELECT tp.id_producto, COUNT(1) AS total
FROM tabla_precio tp
GROUP BY tp.id_producto
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
```

Sobre esto, puedes utilizar un `COUNT` nuevamente:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM (
    SELECT tp.id_producto, COUNT(1) AS total
    FROM tabla_precio tp
    GROUP BY tp.id_producto
    HAVING COUNT(1) > 1) t
```

Aunque en realidad convendría más ejecutar el primer query y luego tras obtener todos los resultados, contar en tu LP (PHP, Java o lo que utilices) cuántos resultados obtuviste.

Answer (score 1):

Para conocer cuales se repiten deberias usar el GROUP BY

```
SELECT a.id_producto, COUNT(*) AS num
 FROM tabla_precio AS a 
GROUP BY a.id_producto
```

[12.20.2 GROUP BY Modifiers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html)

Comment: Te faltó el `HAVING`. Mira que el OP está colocando que solo debe contar repetidos.

Comment: Lo probé y solo me cuenta los repetidos, gracias!

Comment: @AndresMorgado ¿estás diciendo que si tienes un resultado como `1 1` debería contar como repetido? Porque veo que en tu query estás validando que al contar deba ser mayor a 1.

Comment: Tienes razón ...

Answer (score 1):

Ejemplo:

```
select((SELECT count(id_producto) FROM tabla_precio AS a) - (SELECT distinct count(id_producto) 
FROM tabla_precio AS b)) as repetidos from tabla_precio limit 1
```

la idea es restar a la cantidad total de registros la cantidad total de registros sin duplicados, lo que dará la cantidad de registros duplicados